# How to convert into datetime pands df with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like following:

```
|        dates         |
|----------------------|
|                  NaN |
| 2021-12-09T22:00:10Z |
|                  NaN |
|  2018-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2021-12-09T22:00:10Z |
```

What I'm trying to do is applying same format to all those `dates` ignoring all `NaN` values. The desired output:

```
|        dates        |
|---------------------|
|                 NaN |
|2021-12-09 22:00:10  |
|                 NaN |
| 2018-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2021-12-09 22:00:10 |
```

I have tried to do something similar to this but without success:

```py
df.assign(dates=pd.to_datetime(df.dates, errors='ignore').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

output:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Looks like the `NaN`'s are still bothering

The approach I have followed so far is to create a function that is insanciated within a lambda. Inside that function I distinguish if the input value is `NaN` or not. In case it is not, I apply the formatting to the date:

```
def formatting(date: str) -> str:
    if date not in ["nan", "None", "NaN", ""...]: #We can have also nans and nulls masked as Strings!!!!
        date_f = pd.to_datetime(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    else:
        date_f = np.nan
    return date_f


# and then call that method inside lambda
df.dates = df.dates.apply(lambda x: formatting(x))
```

Any suggestions on how to do this better?

Thanks!!!

Comment: try `errors='coerce'` instead of `errors='ignore'` in your first code

Comment: thanks for the answer @Ben.T :) same error... "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" ...

Comment: ok, try with the parameter `utc=True` like `pd.to_datetime(df.dates, errors='coerce', utc=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: It worked! :) many thanks @Ben.T